# Xamarin Forms/Acr.UserDialogs/"Progress" dialog doesn't show percentage

Tags: xamarin.forms

When creating & displaying a Progress dialog:

```
using Acr.UserDialogs;
...
ProgressDialogConfig pdc = new ProgressDialogConfig() { Title = "Hello", AutoShow = true };
ProgDlg = UserDialogs.Instance.Progress(pdc);
ProgDlg.PercentComplete = 33;
```

the dialog DOES appear, but there's no progress-specific UI (should show 33%) and the UI looks exactly like the Acr `Loading` UI (simply a spinner with message).

Does anyone know the trick to cause it to show percentage?

Comment: the Progress dialog in the samples works for me - you might want to compare their syntax to yours

Comment: @Jason Can you provide a link to "their" syntax?

Comment: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/blob/39b2e567e59b8bea14eec4ba3156c8dc6ad5862f/src/Samples/Samples/ViewModels/ProgressViewModel.cs#L48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Jason's link, I found that the `Progress(string)` form **does** show percentage as expected, but the `Progress(ProgressDialogConfig)` **does not**.

Perhaps I was mis-prepping the config, but no matter - I'll just use string form.